# Logging Custom Headers in IIS 7.5 - Cannot find Advanced Logging Module

Tags: iis, iis-7.5

I wish to log a custom header in IIS logs for an application.

On my local machine (Windows 10, IIS 10.0) this is relatively easy:

[image]

On the target machine (Windows Server 2008 R2, IIS 7.5), however the option to add your own fields is not available (Apparently this is only available in IIS 8.5 and above).

I have read instead that you can achieve this same aim by using a module in IIS called Advanced Logging.

I cannot find this option though. In tutorials it appears to the left of the Authentication module in the IIS section (where the arrow below is pointing to).

[image]

Where can I find this? Is there somewhere that I need to install it. I had a look in the "Turn Windows Features On/Off" section but I couldn't find it there.

Comment: IIS 7.x reached end of life a while ago, and all related downloads have been removed from Microsoft Downloads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plese try to use the `Web Platform Installer` to download the installer for this module, something like this:

[image]

Just download this via link:

[image]

Finally you will get this installer,:
[image]

Unfortunately I don't have such an environment to test with, so you'll need to try copying it to the target machine to see if you can install it. If that doesn't fix the issue either, I think you'll have to follow the official recommendation to use [Enhanced Logging for IIS 8.5](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-85/enhanced-logging-for-iis85) or later versions.